# Can Data Explorer queries be run upon private betas by Stack Exchange staff?

Tags: support, data-explorer, private-beta

It seems that private betas, being private, are not on the list of sites that the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) can run against - at least for normal users.

When the *economics* private beta comes online, the ability to run queries against the beta would be nice as we can get a handle on what's working and what isn't at a granularity finer than the Area 51 side bar; for discussion and remedy in the meta.

In lieu of a Data Explorer with private beta access for those users in the private beta<sup>1</sup>, are the Stack Exchange staff that work with the private beta crowd able to occasionally<sup>2</sup> run Data Explorer queries on a private beta if we beg them to in the beta meta?

<sub>1. Perhaps such access exists, I dunno.</sub>
<sub>2. Obviously staff time is limited per beta.</sub>

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what sort of queries would be useful when run against private beta data given that the intention is for the site to not be in private beta for very long.

Comment: @TimStone I was thinking, for example, of a query to graph or list which users have or haven't met their commitment quota; which posts have a long back and forth of commentary; the vote timing spread on Q&As (all at once, trickle-feed, bandwagon) - stuff like that. The duration of the private beta relatively short but also comparably important. Generally when you have less data, you need more sophisticated queries to [extract](http://www.weibull.com/hotwire/issue72/hottopics72.htm) insights.

Comment: @TimStone never underestimate the quantity – and often *quality* – reports an economist can conjure up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, we can. But in practice, the time you're going to spend in beta will be pretty short.

Your focus as a new community should be on asking good questions and posting good answers, ironing out the scope of the site, etc., not on the vote timing spread and similar minutiae.

If you have data requests, you're welcome to post them on the site's meta, but even then keep in mind that we're very unlikely to indulge really specific ones that we feel may detract from productive participation or that focus on specific users rather than statistics in aggregate (e.g. "which users haven't met their commitment" vs "how many posts an average user made so far" -- not that you should be particularly worried about this either during private beta either).

Answer (score 2):

Most of the information in the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) can also be downloaded via the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs). The main advantage of the API is server-side processing, which is invaluable to avoid downloading a few million posts. When the number of posts is in the hundreds, like on an early beta site before the first SEDE dump, you can easily download all the posts and run the data analysis on your machine. For example:

- Which users have or haven't met their commitment quota → [enumerate the posts](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts), sort them by author and count which ones meet what you think are the commitment quota.
- Which posts have a long back and forth of commentary → [enumerate the posts](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts), sort by comment count.
- The vote timing spread on Q&As (all at once, trickle-feed, bandwagon) → vote timing isn't in the API. It's on the data explorer, but with a 1-day granularity, so you wouldn't get much information on the scale of a private beta anyway.