# See number of site views today

Tags: support, private-beta, site-visits

I'm a beta user on [Internet Of Things](http://iot.stackexchange.com).  I've been watching our site views stats for a while, but one thing that bugs me is that appears to be some kind of average.  Would there be a way to see how many views the site had **yesterday** or **December 20th** or something like that?

Obviously, it would be possible to compile a statistic like that once you have access to the 2.5k site analytics, but is there some way you could access this before that point?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get this kind of information from [Quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/iot.stackexchange.com#/trafficCard) as well. I believe it's pretty accurate, as the figures for Stack Overflow are.

[image]

Comment: Wow, same idea, nearly same answers

Answer (score 6):

QuantCast, as noted in another answer, is an external site that provides statistics.

In addition, users who have earned the "View Analytics" privilege (5k on beta sites, 25k on graduated ones) can view SE's [site-analytics page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) (this link is for MSE).  This shows posts (broken down by questions and answers), traffic, and votes.  If you don't have enough reputation to see this, you can ask someone who does -- sharing screen shots for a constructive purpose like building the site is ok.  If your site is too new to have anyone with enough rep, you can ask a moderator.  If your site is too new to have moderators, you'll probably have to wait a bit longer.

You can [ask on your site's meta for data that your community can't get itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243620/162102), but your focus early in beta should be on building the site, not worrying about analytics.  I know that's disappointing to hear, but the data will come in time -- until then, make a site that people will want to visit.

Comment: I know.  It's 2.5K on private betas.  My question was if it was possible without this.  There aren't any 2.5K users yet.  :)

Comment: Oh, didn't realize it's lower on private beta.  You'd need a CM, then.  But private betas are by their nature volatile; stats for one day won't tell you much, really.  I know it's frustrating, but just keep working on building your site, and when you emerge into public and users build up rep and you get mods, everything will fall into place.

Comment: Sure, thanks.  Feel free to join and help out... ;)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243616/can-data-explorer-queries-be-run-upon-private-betas-by-stack-exchange-staff --> *it's not about the numbers* & *focus on content*. Nice hat by the way.

Comment: @Ghanima thanks for the link; I've added that in to cover the private-beta case (which I hadn't noticed was the OP's specific situation).  BTW, I spent about two days with this hat having no idea how I'd gotten it.  I've heard a rumor about it now, but I'm not following all the deep-dive hat analytics.  I'll find out in time, or maybe have occasion to test the rumor.  Meanwhile, fun decoration!